# Differences: 干，办，做，搞，弄

Tags: word-choice, difference, word

What's the difference between all these five words? They mean all "to do", they're driving me crazy! 
I write some example sentences with some of them (hoping that's the right one), just to understand if in some cases they are interchangeable:
我还有几件事要办，得先走了。
他是搞计算机的，有问题可以问他。
我的手机让弟弟给弄坏了。

Thanks for your help, I'd be so grateful.

Answer (score 6):

我还有几件事要（办/做）are basically carry the same meaning, which is official

我还有几件事要（干）I would say this is less formal that the top one, but you can use it in most of the occasions.

他是搞计算机的 here this 搞 = 从事于（engaged in）computer business or industry

but sometimes 搞 can express negative meanings like 他把工作搞得一团糟 he screwed his work, we usually use this as a fixed collocation: 搞得一团糟

弄 usually means casual and sometimes carries bad meanings, for example：

他马上就要弄好了，不要急。casual

弄坏了 you can see this phrase as a fixed collocation, means broke something

Answer (score 4):

汉语动词３８０例 ９０页：

干／搞／弄

### 一、干

１。今天大家干得真不错。

动词＂干＂的意思是做某事／The meaning of 干 is to do some task，如～活儿、～家务事等。

２。他干翻译工作干了几年了？

＂干＂在这儿的意思是担任某种职务或从事某种工作／Here 干 means to be engaged in some work or to be in charge of something，如～队长、～设计工作等。

### 二、搞

１。他搞这种工作很有经验。

动词＂搞＂是表示做某事的意思／搞 means to do or carry out something，如～卫生、～家务、～计划等。＂干＂也可表示这种意思，通常可以互换，但＂搞＂所含的意思更广一些，＂搞＂可以代替一些不容易具体说出的动作／干 and 搞 are sometimes interchangeable，but 搞 has a wider range when referring to certain actions difficult to describe concretely， 如搞对象、搞运动等。＂干＂则不能代替／In these cases， 搞 cannot be replaced by 干。

２。他朋友是搞体育工作的。

＂搞＂在这儿的意思是从事某方面的工作／Here 搞 means to be engaged in a certain type of work，如～生产、～革命等。主要区别是，＂干＂还有担任某种职务的意思，＂搞＂则没有／The difference between 干 and 搞 is that 干 implies taking some post， while 搞 does not。

３。他搞到了两张足球票。

＂搞＂在这儿指设法取得／Here 搞 indicates to manage to get，如～水、～钱、～汽车等。＂干＂不表示这种意思／干 has no such meaning。

### 三、弄

１。他家里弄得很整洁。

动词＂弄＂是表示做某事的意思／弄 means to do something，如～饭、～菜、～卫生等。＂弄＂和＂搞＂都可以代替一些不容易具体说出的动作，这时它们所带的宾语有时不相同，需要注意区别／Both 弄 and 搞 can be used to refer to actions difficult to describe concretely， but sometimes their objects are different，如弄孩子、弄电器、搞恋爱、搞运动等词组中的＂弄＂和＂搞＂分别有照料、修理、进行、参加等不同含义，弄 in ～孩子、～电器 means to take care of and repair， respectively；搞 in ～恋爱，～运动 means to engage in，and to take part in。

２。他弄着了一套新房子。

＂弄＂在这儿是设法取得的意思／Here 弄 means to manage to obtain，如～车、～票、～护照等。＂搞＂也表示设法取得的意思，可以跟＂弄＂互换。＂干＂不表示这种意思／In this case，弄 and  搞 are interchangeable，but 干 cannot be used here。

３。他喜欢弄花儿养鸟。

＂弄＂在这儿的意思是摆弄、玩弄花草或宠物等。＂弄＂有时含有贬义／Here 弄 refers to playing with something carelessly or playing a trick，如～手段等。＂搞＂、＂干＂都不表示这种意思／It is sometimes derogatory。Neither 搞 nor 干 has such a meaning。

Answer (score 1):

Differences: 干，办，做，搞，弄

Oh no! My God!!! (我的妈呀!!!). This is the very question that drives even a native Chinese craze. For another question on 的，得，地, you can probably ignore it and that will not damage anything. But this one, oh, it would kill you at once if you abuse them at the right time and the right place. I am warning you that there are dirty (sx) stories of them everywhere, especially 干 and 搞.

Unfortunately, there is no official answer to this question. In spoken language, it may very depend on the custom of different places. In written, it depends on the style of the article.  For example, some authors intentionally offset the meaning of one of the words, just to amuse the reader or emphasize some characters. 
Therefore, we'd better stay in the middle to be safe. One may want to say the following:

干事情（任何事情）

办公事（正式的办公室的事情）

做工作（动手做的事情）

搞卫生（动作比较大的）

弄坏了东西（需要技术，但是没有这个技术）

Answer (score 0):

需要注意一些有可能会冒犯人的用法：干、办、搞、弄，当他们和人放在一起的时候就是带侵略性的
比如：
我干死你 = 我办了你 =  我弄死你 = 我搞死你 = i will kill you