# Is 弄 + complement of result only used for actions with a negative outcome?

Tags: usage

[MDBG translates 弄](http://www.mdbg.net/chindict/chindict.php?page=worddict&wdrst=0&wdqb=%E5%BC%84) as "to do / to manage / to handle / to play with / to fool with / to mess with / to fix / to toy with". When I look at example sentences with 弄 and a complement of result, I find only descriptions of actions that are somehow negative:

> - 他把我的电脑**弄坏了**。 ([Yale University Center for Language Study](http://comet.cls.yale.edu/mandarin/content/result/grammar/Result-8.htm))
> - 小狗把房间**弄得很乱**。
> - 请不要把顺序**弄乱了**。
> - 我不小心把衣服**弄脏了**。(Last three examples from [Mandarin Chinese School: New HSK Level 4 Vocabulary (Chinese-English)](http://www.mandarinchineseschool.com/files/HSK/New_HSK_Level_IV_Vocabulary.pdf))

Can 弄 only have a negative complement? Or is this just the most common usage? (If positive outcomes after 弄 are possible, please provide an example.) 
Note that I am interested in 普通话 rather than local dialects.

Comment: suggestion：examine jukuu's examples for 弄：13.tighten the rope a tittle 把绳子弄紧15.  After much tugging,the rope untangled itself and straightened out.拉了好久才把缆绳解开弄直。17.  Anything will do to keep the door open.
 随便什么东西都能把门弄开。

Comment: esp. note jukuu's examples for 弄明白(１００),  弄清楚 (１００),  弄好(４１)

Comment: @user6065 Could you please expand your comments into an answer? That would be more useful. Comments aren't meant to answer questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No，it can be followed by positive outcomes.

In your examples, they are followed by adjectives such as 乱、坏、脏, which are correct.

However, you can also say

> 我的电脑坏了，是李明帮我弄好的。My computer was broken, Ming Li fixed it for me.
>
> 你能帮我弄一下吗？Can you help me to do/fix this?
>
> 他把这个弄得很漂亮、很整齐。He made it very pretty and tidy.

In conclusion, 弄 can be followed by both positive or negative outcomes.

Comment: duplicate of at least comment #2, it seems most users would consider 明白、清楚、好 as positive

Comment: @user6065 so what do you expect me to do?

Comment: Some users might suggest:avoid unnecessary duplication!有某些用户很可能建议避免不必要的重复。

Comment: @user6065 Since you did not submit an answer, I do not consider EmmaXL's answer as duplication. Sorry.

Comment: Just being allowed to comment already is a great favor. Besides some users are afraid their answers will be marked down, which means their score will go down. In fact there seem to be some powerful users who will miss no opportunity to take revenge on other users and mark their answers down. For this reason these users restrict themselves to writing comments.有用户认为，仅仅被允许撰写评论本身就是十分多么大的恩惠。 此外有用户害怕其答案很可能会受到扣分，导致得分会被减少的。好像有些力量大的用户总是伺机向别的用户报仇而使其答案受到扣分。因此后者就限制自己只是提供评论而不是任何答案。

Comment: also see the part concerning 弄 of http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/12290/differences-%E5%B9%B2-%E5%8A%9E-%E5%81%9A-%E6%90%9E-%E5%BC%84

Comment: @user6065 "there seem to be some powerful users who will miss no opportunity to take revenge on other users": if this is true, that is really sad and it should be addressed in a meta question.

Comment: users flock to this site to learn, not to amass points, in addition users are amply rewarded by having their comments published at this site, 大多数用户之所以群集于本网站是因为想学习而不是因为想领取尽量大的分数，另外对大多数用户来说可以发布自己的评论就意味着得到充分的报偿